# strok is not properly tokenizing words

Tags: c, token

I am attempting to tokenize and store separate words into an array but for some reason the first word gets stored in index 0 and the rest of the words are not tokenized and are all stored in index 1.
I have the following code....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   
    char input[300];

    while (1)
    {
       
        printf ("\nEnter input to check or q to quit\n");
        fgets(input, 300, stdin);

        for (int j = 0; j < 300; j++)
        {
            input[j] = tolower(input[j]);
        }

        /* remove the newline character from the input */
        int i = 0;
        while (input[i] != '\n' && input[i] != '\0')
        {
            i++;
        }
        input[i] = '\0';


        /* check if user enter q or Q to quit program */
        if ( (strcmp (input, "q") == 0) || (strcmp (input, "Q") == 0) )
            break;

        //printf ("%s\n", input);
        /*Start tokenizing the input into words separated by space
        *The tokenized words are added to an array of words*/

        char delim[] = " ";
        char *ptr = strtok(input, delim);
        int j = 0 ;

        
        // allocate our array
        char *wordList[15];
        for (i = 0 ; i < 16; i++)
        {
            wordList[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 300);
        }

        while (ptr != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(wordList[j], ptr);
            printf ("%s\n", wordList[j]);
            ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
            j++;
        }
        printf ("%s\n", wordList[1]);
    }

    printf ("\nGoodbye\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output

```
hello
there 
sir
```

Output I'm getting

```
hello 
there sir
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you enable all compiler warnings and fix the warnings? If not, please do that then update your code+results/

Comment: Not liking the various magic numbers - 300, 15 - there’s a reason people use constant variables and the need to have repeated references to constants defined in only one place are the sort of reason for that.

Comment: Let’s say just for the sake of discussion that your user actually input 300 characters as allowed by your fgets call, how many bytes would that need to store the string?

Comment: So define a const int stringlength=300; then size the array to stringlength+1 to allow for the terminating ‘\0’ and use stringlength in the for loop. Now you’ve only got one place to change if you change the string length.

Answer (score 2):

This loop

```
        // allocate our array
        char *wordList[15];
        for (i = 0 ; i < 16; i++)
        {
            wordList[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 300);
        }
```

is bad because it is writing to `wordList[15]` while only `wordList[0]` to `wordList[14]` are available.
`delim` may be placed just after `wordList` and writing to this out-of-range `wordList[15]` may break the contents of `delim`.

Increase the number of elements

```
        // allocate our array
        char *wordList[16];
        for (i = 0 ; i < 16; i++)
        {
            wordList[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 300);
        }
```

Or decrease the number of iteration.

```
        // allocate our array
        char *wordList[15];
        for (i = 0 ; i < 15; i++)
        {
            wordList[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 300);
        }
```

Comment: The code shouldn’t be using 15/16 - these should be defined as a const and then numbers added/subtracted.

Comment: @barny What do you mean by "numbers added/subtracted"? Anyway, I think using `300` instead of `15` and `16` here is better because the input is at most 300 characters, so there will never be more than 300 tokens. Then replacing all `300`s with macro will make the code better.

Comment: Define `const int ntokens=15;` then size wordList using ntokens and the for loop to use ntokens. Try to avoid macros where possible, they’re less maintainable.